# Is Gmail Priority Inbox only for Google Apps accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I don't see Gmail Priority Inbox feature in normal Gmail account, but the option to activate is there on my Google Apps gmail. So, wondering is this Priority thing has been launched only for Apps??

Answer (score 5):

> Priority Inbox will be rolling out to all Gmail users, including those of you who use Google Apps, over the next week or so.

[Info taken from here.](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/email-overload-try-priority-inbox.html)

Hope this helps.